# Re installing Catboost 0.22 or 0.23

Tags: python, catboost

I had old version catboost 0.23 or probably 0.22 don't remember , but sure one of these was on my machine. Somehow catboost new version 0.23.1 has been released and get installed in my machine. I noticed my model which was trained on old version had good performance , same old model with same old features/data and data processing, everything same is giving a little bit off performance on catboost 0.23.1. Previously recall was 0.77 now it has been 0.74 , data is also same ,preprocessing is also same.

I doubt there is some issue with new version want to double check ,for that what i want to uninstall catboost which i did but getting nowhere old version of catboost 0.22 , any body has any clue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly specify package version using pip like this:
`pip install catboost==0.23`

Comment: i did the same last night but with conda and it did not work , using your pip suggested worked. Dont know what is wrong with Anaconda